# Expecting member declaration for BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a Broadcastreceiver. Without the onDestroy, the app run. Since this Broadcast is created programmatically, i need to use the onDestroy when not using it. What I need to do with the unregisterReceiver().

Thanks

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var receiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     btnSetUp.setOnClickListener {
       SetUpBroadcastReceiver()
     }

}


private fun SetUpBroadcastReceiver() {

    val filter = IntentFilter()
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")
    receiver = CallReceiver()
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter)

}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    if (receiver != null) unregisterReceiver(receiver)
}﻿
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Register Broadcast in manifest file like this

```
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: tried your approach, Not working. I m using dynamically create broadcastreceiver. I m not using this approach to insert intent filter in Manifest.